# Rhythmbox - How can I calculate BPMs?

Tags: rhythmbox

Where and how can I download BPMs of my songs? (Would be a nice feature because I'm doing some running.)

Comment: AFAIK Rythmbox doesn't have this functionality. You could calculate them I suppose or look them up. You might get some suggestions on this at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: In the overview of my songs I see a rider "BPM". Is it  only meant for manual input?

Comment: You can use bpm-tools package: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/bpm.1.html If you have problems with mp3, take a look at: https://superuser.com/questions/421153/how-to-add-a-mp3-handler-to-sox